# For every natural integer $N>3$ there are at least two distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $\dfrac{p+q}{2}=N$ and $N-p=q-N$, $(p<q)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, goldbachs-conjecture

I'm not sure but this problem may be similar or related to Goldbach conjecture? Any proof/disproof, insight and opinion is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a Goldbach's conjecture and $p+q/2=N$ implies $N-p=q-N$. Recently, Harold Helfgot proved that every odd natural number can be written as sum of three primes.

Comment: Thanks for the info... @Euler88...

Comment: But $p+q=N$ implies $N-p=q-N$ is not true. For instance: $24=\dfrac{41+7}{2}$ where, $41$ and $7$ are prime and $24-7\neq{41-24}$. @Euler88...

Comment: ...both of those are equal to 17?

Comment: $24-7=17=41-24$

Comment: @user18724 $(p+q)/2$

Comment: Oops! I see...thanks again for correcting me fellas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the two equations you give are equivalent;
$$N-p=q-N\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 2N=p+q\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad N=\frac{p+q}{2}.$$
The problem you give is slightly stronger than the Goldbach conjecture:

Suppose for every natural number $N>3$ there are two distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that
$$N=\frac{p+q}{2},$$
For every *even* natural number $M$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $M=2N$. By assumption there exist distinct primes $p$ and $q$ such that $N=\tfrac{p+q}{2}$, from which it follows that
$$M=2N=2\cdot\frac{p+q}{2}=p+q.$$
So every even natural number is then the sum of two distinct primes, which is slightly stronger than Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Interesting answer. Thanks for the demonstration. @Servaes